# How to avoid duplication in a crawler

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I wrote a crawler using the scrapy framework in python to select some links and meta tags.It then crawls the start urls and write the data in a JSON encoded format onto a file.The problem is that when the crawler is run two or three times with the same start urls the data in the file gets duplicated .To avoid this I used a downloader middleware in scrapy which is this : http://snippets.scrapy.org/snippets/1/

What I did was copy and paste the above code in a file inside my scrapy project and I enabled it in the settings.py file by adding the following line:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {'a11ypi.removeDuplicates.IgnoreVisitedItems':560}
```

where "a11ypi.removeDuplicates.IgnoreVisitedItems" is the class path name and finally I went in and modified my items.py file and included the following fields

```
visit_id = Field()  
visit_status = Field()
```

But this doesn't work and still the crawler produces the same result appending it to the file when run twice

I did the writing to the file in my pipelines.py file as follows:

```
import json 

class AYpiPipeline(object):  
    def __init__(self):  
    self.file = open("a11ypi_dict.json","ab+")


   # this method is called to process an item after it has been scraped.


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
    d = {}  

    i = 0
    # Here we are iterating over the scraped items and creating a dictionary of dictionaries.
    try:
        while i<len(item["foruri"]):
        d.setdefault(item["foruri"][i],{}).setdefault(item["rec"][i],{})[item["foruri_id"][i]] = item['thisurl'] + ":" +item["thisid"][i]
        i+=1
    except IndexError:
        print "Index out of range"

    json.dump(d,self.file)
        return item
```

And my spider code is as follows:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from a11ypi.items import AYpiItem

class AYpiSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "a11y.in"
    allowed_domains = ["a11y.in"]

    # This is the list of seed URLs to begin crawling with.
    start_urls = ["http://www.a11y.in/a11ypi/idea/fire-hi.html"]

    # This is the callback method, which is used for scraping specific data
    def parse(self,response):
    temp = []
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = AYpiItem()
    wholeforuri = hxs.select("//@foruri").extract()            # XPath to extract the foruri, which contains both the URL and id in foruri
    for i in wholeforuri:
        temp.append(i.rpartition(":"))

    item["foruri"] = [i[0] for i in temp]     # This contains the URL in foruri
    item["foruri_id"] = [i.split(":")[-1] for i in wholeforuri]  # This contains the id in foruri
    item['thisurl'] = response.url                                  
    item["thisid"] = hxs.select("//@foruri/../@id").extract()
    item["rec"] = hxs.select("//@foruri/../@rec").extract()
    return item
```

Kindly suggest what to do.

Comment: Please format your code properly

Answer (score 1):

try to understand why the snippet is written as it is:

```
 if isinstance(x, Request):
            if self.FILTER_VISITED in x.meta:
                visit_id = self._visited_id(x)
                if visit_id in visited_ids:
                    log.msg("Ignoring already visited: %s" % x.url,
                            level=log.INFO, spider=spider)
                    visited = True
```

Notice in line 2, you actually require a key in in Request.meta called `FILTER_VISITED` in order for the middleware to drop the request. The reason is well-intended because every single url you have visited will be skipped and you will not have urls to tranverse at all if you do not do so. So, `FILTER_VISITED` actually allows you to choose what url patterns you want to skip. If you want links extracted with a particular rule skipped, just do

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('url_regex1', 'url_regex2' )),  callback='my_callback', process_request = setVisitFilter)

def setVisitFilter(request):
   request.meta['filter_visited'] = True
   return request
```

P.S I do not know if it works for 0.14 and above as some of the code has changed for storing spider context in the sqlite db.